# DockerFile / Switch from ubuntu:latest to alpine:3.3

Tags: python, docker

I create my own docker file with the following, and everything works well:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y  install  libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python-pip python-setuptools python2.7 git tox
```

Now I try to switch to `FROM alpine:3.3`, so I wrote the following

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk add --no-cache libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python-pip python-setuptools python2.7 git tox
```

But it gives me the following:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  build-essential (missing):
    required by: world[build-essential]
  libssl-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libssl-dev]
  libxslt1-dev (missing):
    required by: world[libxslt1-dev]
  python-pip (missing):
    required by: world[python-pip]
  python-setuptools (missing):
    required by: world[python-setuptools]
  python2.7 (missing):
    required by: world[python2.7]
  tox (missing):
    required by: world[tox]
  zlib1g-dev (missing):
    required by: world[zlib1g-dev]
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [frolvlad/alpine-python2](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-python2/) image.

`FROM frolvlad/alpine-python2
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk \
                     libxml2-dev \
                     libxslt-dev \
                     python-dev \
                     openssl-dev \
                     libffi-dev \
                     zlib-dev \
                     py-pip`

And *tox* you can do install via *pip*